# R: reading a 64MB file fills GBs of RAM - why?

Tags: r, readfile

I have an R script that reads a (fixed width) file (size 64mb) with the following command:

```
data <- read.fwf("data.txt", width=rep(16, 561), n=row.limit, colClasses = "character")
```

The file has 561 columns and ~7000 lines.
When executing the command the main memory of the system starts to fill up until the maximum of 4GB is reached - which then maked the system unusable.

Why do R require here GBs of memory when loading a 64mb file?

How could I improve the reading of the file?

Thankd and regards!

Comment: set `buffersize = 500` as an argument in the function and try again

Comment: setting the buffersize did not have any effect. But I now replaced read.fwf with read.table - and now it works and consumes only very little memory.